# my.cnf in applications/MAMP/conf stops mysql server from starting

Tags: php, mamp, mysql

I am trying to increase the max_allowed_packet which I have changed to 999M and create my.cnf in because I can not seem to find the my.cnf which mysql uses to edit that line.

Now It is has stopped turning on since I moved into my folder. conf folder in MAMP.

Comment: have you tried to start your mysql with admin permission ? or is it  on a server ?

Comment: This will sound absolutely stupid on my end, how do I start it in admin permission? I am not that used to mac.

Comment: hmmm didn't know it was mac, guess you have to google it. in windows you run into problems sometimes if you just start it normal

Comment: Alrights thanks man, is there any other solutions someone could offer me?

Comment: Anyone? still stuck on this problem